# Strong Induction on Lists

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

I'm trying to prove that a proposition `P` holds for every element of a type `A`. Unfortunately, I only know how to prove `P` for a given `a:A` if I have access to proofs of `P` for all `a'` less than `a`.

This should be provable by induction on a list containing all elements of `A`, starting with the smallest element in `A` and then incrementally proving that `P` holds for all other elements, but I just can't get it to work.

Formally, the problem is the following:

```
Parameter A : Type.
Parameter lt : A -> A -> Prop.
Notation "a < b" := (lt a b).
Parameter P : A -> Prop.
Parameter lma : forall a, (forall a', a' < a -> P a') -> P a.

Goal forall a, P a.
```

I may have made a mistake formalizing this problem. Feel free to assume reasonable constraints on the inputs, e.g. `A` can be assumed to be enumerable, `lt` can be transitive, decidable ...

Comment: For an inductive proof to hold you need the base case. Do you have it in your formulation?

Comment: The base case `P a`, for the `a` that is smaller than all other `a'`, can be proven easily from `lma` because the second argument to `lma` holds vacuously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to prove that the relation is well-founded. There's a relevant [standard library](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Wf.html) module. From there, you should prove `well_founded A` for your `A` type, and then you can use `well_founded_ind` to prove `P` for all values.

Answer (score 4):

This looks at lot like [well founded induction](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Wf.html). If you can prove that your `lt` function is well-founded, then your goal becomes trivial. You can find example of such proofs on naturals [here](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Arith.Wf_nat.html)